# Kafka Streams access latest value before window

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a windowed stream which needs to calculate a value based on all values which occurred within the window PLUS the latest value which occurred before the window.

```
inputStream.groupByKey
  .windowedBy(timeWindow)
  .aggregate(Aggregation()) {
    case (_, value, aggregation) =>
      // ...
  }
  .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
  .toStream
  .map((windowed, aggregation) => {
    // here I need access to the last value which
    // occurred before the window
  }
  .to("output")
```

How can I get access to the previous value in this stage of my stream?

Comment: After some more thinking, would it be reasonable to implement a custom aggregator and drop the `windowedBy`? If there are better ways, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Processor API and write a custom `Processor` (or if you embed it into the DSL you can use `transform()`) with attached windowed store. Note that a windowed-stores is also just a key-value store, with key being compose of the record-key and the start timestamp of the window.